# Add the second element of list from other list if the first elements are equal (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have two lists
b1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {9, 3},{15,2}},
b2 = {{1, 7}, {3, 6}, {8, 5}, {9, 7}}

My goal is to add the second element of both lists if the first elements are equal and preserve the elements differents in both lists.

{{1,9},{3,10},{4,5},{8,5},{9,10},{15,2}}

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I'm trying to add the lists generated in a cycle of my simulation. But, I have the problem that the list elements are not the same (in the first coordinate) in all the cases. At the end, I need a list of all the contributions in a list for plotting.

Answer (score 2):

```
b1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {9, 3}, {15, 2}};
b2 = {{1, 7}, {3, 6}, {8, 5}, {9, 7}};

u = Union@Join[b1, b2][[All, 1]];
Map[{#, Total[Flatten[{
       Cases[b1, {#, _}],
       Cases[b2, {#, _}]}[[All, All, -1]]]]} &, u]
```

> {{1, 9}, {3, 10}, {4, 5}, {8, 5}, {9, 10}, {15, 2}}

Or

```
g = GroupBy[Join[b1, b2], First -> Last];
Sort[{#1, Total[#2]} & @@@ Normal[g]]
```

> {{1, 9}, {3, 10}, {4, 5}, {8, 5}, {9, 10}, {15, 2}}

Or just

```
Sort[Normal[GroupBy[Join[b1, b2], First -> Last, Total]] /. Rule -> List]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your two lists were the same length then you could use Thread to pair up the arguments. Then you could write a function to test each pair to decide what do do with them. That would work fine except you don't want the two arguments changed if the first items don't match. To overcome that problem you could use the Sequence trick.

```
b1={{1,2},{3,4},{4,5},{9,3}}; b2={{1,7},{3,6},{8,5},{9,7}};
f[{a_,b_},{c_,d_}]:=If[a==c,{a,b+d},Sequence@@{{a,b},{c,d}}];
Thread[f[b1,b2]]
```

All that returns

```
{{1,9},{3,10},{4,5},{8,5},{9,10}}
```

Is that exactly correct for every pair of equal length lists?

BUT you have edited your question to allow unequal length lists. Thread is not going to work with that. But perhaps you can write a function to be used over the top of this. It will check if the list lengths are equal, if so then do what has been shown, if not then trim off the longer list, use what has been shown and finally append the extra item from the longer list.

Can you figure out how to do that?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This might appeal

```
Sort[Join[b1, b2]] //. {a:___, {m_, n_}, {m_, p_}, z:___} :> {a, {m, n + p}, z}
```

Not terrifically thoroughly tested.